# MySQL UPDATE = are there any overheads in updating fields with same contents?

Tags: mysql

I have an application that needs to evaluate a bunch of 'messages" every 2 second interval..

Everytime this evaluation is run, the system is design to SELECT current row and column data, do something with it then update it back into the table. the script is setup in a way that it UPDATE all fields regardless of actual changes or not (for the sake of cleaner coding) .. it's like this:

- select all rows from MESSAGES table
- globalize the variables
- select all rows from MESSAGES_REMOTE table
- globalize the variables // this effectively overwrites existing
  variables from the first table
- UPDATE back ALL the variables into the MESSAGES table

Now, the actual updated columns may range from 1 variable to all variables , depending on the situation..

So I was wondering if MYSQL would have the same overhead when trying to update columns w/ the SAME VALUE or does it have some sort of internal engine to check if an actual update / write needs to be carried out

Comment: tnx man , good reading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
 SELECT * FROM user;
 +---------+----------+
 | user_id | username |
 +---------+----------+
 |     101 | Adam     |
 |     102 | Ben      |
 |     103 | Charlie  |
 |     104 | Dave     |
 +---------+----------+
 4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

 UPDATE user SET username = 'Adam' WHERE user_id = 101;
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
 Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: yep, it pretty much does .. i see it that on mines too but im also concerned w/ what happens in the background too and how much overhead mysql takes to "check" each column whenever it's updating something.. but the other thread as linked by @stan mcgeek answers this question pretty well , thank you very much for taking the time :)

Answer (score 0):

While http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html mentions that:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

it doesn't mean that there is no overhead.

I did some benchmark on a table with 86 columns, by opening a connection and then perform 1000 UPDATE's on a single row.

In scenario 1, all 86 columns are set to the same value. This took 557ms.

In scenario 2, only 3 columns are set to the same value. This took 290ms.

So, there is definitely some overhead in IO read and CPU.